# How to get the user name and password from my app?

Tags: iphone

I want to get the user name and password from my devise as shown in the attached image.Can somebody please give me any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Settings Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have created setting bundle in your application.

then just write:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"username"]`
`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"password"]`

and you get the value.

Comment: You shouldn't save passwords in `NSUserDefaults`. Use the keychain instead.